# How to create android app bundle (aab) file with signed upload key for release?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play, apk, mobile-application

I have already uploaded an app in Google Play with Google Play App Signing. But while I want to release an upgrade version of the app, I need to generate new Android App Bundle (aab) file using Android Studio. I have included the key path store after downloading the Upload Certificate. But, couldn't generate the signed aab file.

[image: Goole Play App Signing]

[image]

[image: **Error**]

[image]

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: I wonder if you're using the proper keystore that is related to this project? If yes, then have you generated multiple keystores?

Comment: No only once. In key store path should I select the path for keystore or I should download the Upload Certificate File and then include that file with this keystore path?

Comment: You might have published this app before. so while publishing it, you would have generated a keystor, you should use the same keystore each time rather than generating a new one each time..

Comment: and as for your question if you have your keystore with you select the keystore path correctly no need to download upload certificate file..

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same keystore. But it, shows the above error. I've updated my post again.

Comment: I still don't understand if you have uploaded the app with your key or the one generated from the play store upload key in the previous app upload!?

Comment: Which should I include as a key path? keystore.jks or upload_certificate.pem while I sign the app for release?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#enroll_new. Just have a look at this.. keystore.jks